# Javascript Group by date inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of key value pairs and I would like to group it together based on date.  The `gameDate` is actually like "2014-01-01 12:00:00" so I'm splitting it and trying to use the date as key.

```
var a = {};
(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
        if (a[games[i]['gameDate'].split(' ')[0]]) {
            var b = [];
            b = [a[games[i]['gameDate'].split(' ')[0]]];
            b.push(games[i]);
            a[games[i]['gameDate'].split(' ')[0]] = b;
        }else {
            a[games[i]['gameDate'].split(' ')[0]] = games[i];
        }
    }
})();
console.log(a);
```

I've "googled" for quite some time...I think what I'm trying to get is an array of objects...but this is the closest I could get and it's still very messed up.  I would like to group all `games[i]` based on their date.  Please help out.

```
for (var i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
        if ([games[i]['gameDate'].split(' ')[0]] in a) {
            var b = [];
            b = a[games[i]['gameDate'].split(' ')[0]];
            b.push(games[i]);
            a[games[i]['gameDate'].split(' ')[0]] = b;
        }else {
            a[games[i]['gameDate'].split(' ')[0]] = [];
            a[games[i]['gameDate'].split(' ')[0]].push(games[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the dates REALLY formatted without padding 0 in the month and day? If so you need to split on "-" too and create a date object

Comment: @mplungjan No, they have zeros, they're coming from a database.  I don't think it matters that much for the question.  I just wrote it quickly as an example

Comment: You are correct it does not matter. I did waste some time making sure the key of the object was a proper string, but it seems that yyyy-mm-dd is ok at least in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```js
var games = [{
  gameDate: "2015-01-01 12:00:00",
  gameName: "bla 1"}, {
  gameDate: "2015-01-02 12:00:00",
  gameName: "bla 2"}, {
  gameDate: "2015-01-02 12:00:00",
  gameName: "bla 3"} ]
// ----------


var a = {};
for (var i=0; i < games.length;i++) {
  var d = games[i]['gameDate'].split(' ')[0];
  if (!a[d]) a[d] = [];
  a[d].push(games[i]);
}
console.log(a)

// this one destroys the original array but uses proper strings as keys

var a = {};
while (games.length) {
  var dateString = games[0]['gameDate'].split(' ')[0].replace(/-/g, "");
  if (!a["d" + dateString]) {
    a["d" + dateString] = [];
  }
  a["d" + dateString].push(games.shift());
}
console.log(a)
```

Comment: I wanted to group it daily into key value pairs, key being the date `2014-01-01`, `2014-01-02`, etc.

Comment: I got the desired result a little while ago.  I swear I looked at every possible "json key value array", "object with value arrays", "array of objects", etc...didn't think it would be this difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
for (var i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
    var date = games[i]['gameDate'].split(' ')[0];
    if (!a[date]) {
        a[date] = [];
    }
    a[date].push(games[i]);
}
```

Comment: That is in effect identical to  what I did. I just made sure the array index was a non-numeric string without special chars

Comment: Is it what you wanted to get? If no, plese write down an example of the result object (`a`).